# Implement Java/JavaFX on ARM

Tags: linux, java, embedded, arm

I am working on ARM Linux.

I have found this [link](http://jdk7.java.net/fxarmpreview/javafx-arm-developer-preview.html) that says that JavaFX could work on ARM.

I am confused about [Embedded Java SE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/downloads/javase/index.html) and [JavaFx ARM](http://jdk7.java.net/fxarmpreview/index.html). Do I need to setup a JVM for those or not?

I have compiled my own kernel and built a functional root file system with **busybox**, **glibc library** and **ARM cross compiler toolchains**.

Should I need to implement a JVM to get the J2SE and JavaFX platform?

I just want to build a small Java based OS especially using JavaFX. I have the `glibc-2.9` library to run the framework as said by the requirement to run [Embedded J2SE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/downloads/javase/index.html). But there is no tutorial about how to install or set it up to work. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays as support of JFX for ARM by Oracle is stopped I would try a https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX